# В чем отличие OpenCV ML от Tensorflow? Что лучше применять?

Tags: opencv, tensorflow

Возможно вопрос не совсем корректен, но все же
В чем отличие OpenCV ML от Tensorflow? Что лучше применять?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос слишком общий и выбор полностью зависит от поставленных задач. Библиотеки не просто разные, у них совершенно разное назначение. Если кратко:

- OpenCV содержит реализации различных алгоритмов машинного зрения. Методов машинного обучения там реализовано всего пара штук.
- Tensorflow — это библиотека для работы с тензорами общего назначения, без привязки к конкретной области. Но в ней реализовано автодифференцирование, методы оптимизации и возможность задействовать GPU для вычислений произвольной сложности.

Если ваше приложение должно лишь найти лицо на фотографии или с помощью кластеризации уменьшить палитру изображения, то проще взять OpenCV. Там это делается парой строк.

Если же вы обучаете нейронную сеть оригинальной архитектуры для цифровой обработки изображений, то тут, конечно, придётся воспользоваться Tensorflow.